# ASP.NET Core MVC main method question: What do these arrow functions mean?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Can anyone help go through this code and tell me what the arrow functions means in this context? I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it...

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => //and here
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => //here
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Do the arrow functions in these two scenarios refer to different things?

Answer (score 1):

When the body of your method has only one line, you can use arrow function To be less code. They are not very different

even you can write this way:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => //here
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
    }
```

**or:**

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => 
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => //here
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
   }
```

---

**for your second question**

```
  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => 
        {
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

this is a [Lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

> You use a lambda expression to create an anonymous function. Use the lambda declaration operator => to separate the lambda's parameter list from its body. A lambda expression can be of any of the following two forms: